# Delphi GDIPLUS change image position

Tags: image, delphi, gdi+

i am trying to achieve a simple task but by using GDI+ and i cannot find any example.
In my code i need to change an image position (top if to be more specific), but i have no idea if i can do it in a better way. 
This is how i do it now:

```
procedure TForm2.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if image1.Top = -93 then
  Begin
    for I := -93 to -1 do
    Begin
    Sleep(10);
    image1.Top := Image1.Top + 1;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  End;
End else if image1.Top = 0 then
Begin
  for I := 0 downto -92 do
  Begin
    Sleep(10);
    image1.Top := Image1.Top - 1;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  End;
End;
end;
```

Well it's pretty simple, but it does not go smooth, but jumps and redraws itself at each step.

I appreciate your help.

UPDATE:
Thanks to TLama and his inspiration i have found [this](http://www.mitov.com/products/igdi+) GDIPlus implementation for delphi 2007

Comment: You might want to look into double-buffering animation.

Comment: @Warren, moving controls is a wrong way to animate anything! You should remember the position of what you want to draw, modify it in the `OnTimer` event and tell the system you want to invalidate the control.

Comment: Certainly.  However double buffering animated techniques plus drawing on a canvas, works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving control is a wrong way to animate anything, GDI+ independent. Instead, you should remember the position you want to change for the animation, modify it in the `OnTimer` event and tell the system that you want to invalidate the target control. Then in the control's `OnPaint` event you should render whatever you want by that position.

So as the first, replace your `TImage` component by a `TPaintBox` since the `TImage` is used mainly for static images, not for a dynamic rendering. Also use two timers. One for upward animation and one for downward animation.

The following code doesn't take into account approximation of a timer, and it uses less known [`Delphi 2009 GDI+ Library`](http://www.bilsen.com/gdiplus/index.shtml) wrapper for Delphi:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, GdiPlus;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Timer2: TTimer;
    PaintBox1: TPaintBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
  private
    GPImage: IGPImage;
    FImageTop: Integer;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FImageTop := 0;
  Timer1.Interval := 15;
  Timer2.Interval := 15;
  DoubleBuffered := True;
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
  Timer2.Enabled := False;
  GPImage := TGPImage.Create('d:\Image.jpg');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // no need for the following line since it's a reference of the interface
  // GPImage := nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (FImageTop > -93) then
  begin
    FImageTop := FImageTop - 1;
    PaintBox1.Invalidate;
  end
  else
  begin
    Timer1.Enabled := False;
    Timer2.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (FImageTop < 0) then
  begin
    FImageTop := FImageTop + 1;
    PaintBox1.Invalidate;
  end
  else
  begin
    Timer2.Enabled := False;
    Timer1.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
var
  GPGraphics: IGPGraphics;
begin
  GPGraphics := TGPGraphics.Create(PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle);
  GPGraphics.DrawImage(GPImage, 0, FImageTop);
end;

end.
```

Comment: +1 but I would not use 2 Timers ....     FImageTop := FImageTop + FStepDistance;
  if (FImageTop > 99) or (FImageTop < 1) then
    FStepDistance := -FStepDistance;

Comment: Thanks TLama, that's exactly what i wanted!

Comment: Ah, although the question is already answered, i would like to ask what if i want to use PNG instead of JPG?

Comment: That's the beauty of GDI+ It has a [`built in support`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535370(v=vs.85).aspx) for BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, TIFF and EMF file decoders. So simply load that file and you're done!

Comment: I just got to my PC and was so excited to test but then i realized that i have D2007 and no GDIplus, so trying to find a workaround... :(

Comment: I don't have it neither in Delphi 2009. You can find a few wrappers for it on the Internet. I've used here and I usually suggest to use [`this one`](http://www.bilsen.com/gdiplus/index.shtml).